# apt-xapian-index, how to limit its disk usage or safely move it away?

Tags: disk-usage, cache

My `/var/cache/apt-xapian-index` has 4.5GB.

I like the synaptic search functionality a lot, but that price is too much for my small SSD...

I was thinking what I can do about it, to keep it available and also not be a disk usage issue:

- I would like to know if we can limit that size in some way?
- May be if that folder could be compressed?
- Or if it could be moved to another partition/HD, safely in a way that it would not break synaptic (or something else that also uses it) in case such partition is not mounted?
- Or some way to partially clean it, like removing information of packages that I do not care about?
- Or, may be, the xapian index could be restricted to only providing a limited indexing, so propably some data as the description of a package (as I guess it is being indexed), could be excluded from the indexing?